# Caixa de buscar no larável

Tags: php, laravel

Não consigo buscar as informações do banco de dados.

Esse é meu `controller`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\registrar;

class registrarcontroller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $registros = registrar::all();
        return view('admin.registrar.index',compact('registros'));
    }
    public function adicionar()
    {
        return view('admin.registrar.adicionar');

    }
    public function salvar(Request $req)
    {
        $dados = $req->all();



        registrar::create($dados);

        return redirect()->route('admin.registrar');
    }

    public function editar($id)
    {
        $registro = registrar::find($id);
        return view('admin.registrar.editar',compact('registro'));
    }


     public function buscar($id)
    {
        $registro = registrar::find($id);
        return view('admin.registrar.buscar',compact('registro'));
    }


    public function atualizar(Request $req, $id)
    {
        $dados = $req->all();

        registrar::find($id)->update($dados);

        return redirect()->route('admin.registrar');

    }

}
```

**View**

```
@extends('layout.site')

@section('titulo','adicionar')

@section('conteudo')
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="center">BUSCAR OCORRÊNCIAS</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <form class="" action="{{route('admin.registrar.buscar',$registro->id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
                @include('admin.registrar._form')
                <button class="btn deep-orange">Buscar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Campo de busca

```
<h3 class="center">LISTA DE OCORRÊNCIAS</h3>
<div class="row">
<table>
        <div class="row">
          <a>
            <input type="text" id="texto" name="buscar" placeholder="Buscar"> 
         </a>
          <a class="btn blue" href="{{ route('admin.registrar.buscar') }}">Buscar</a>
          <a class="btn blue" href="{{ route('admin.registrar.adicionar') }}">Adicionar</a>
        </div>

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Data-Nasc</th>
            <th>Hora ocorrência</th>
            <th>Hora chegada</th>
            <th>Hora liberação</th>
            <th>Numero CNH</th>
            <th>CPF</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($registros as $regitro)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $regitro->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $regitro->condutor}}</td>
            <td>{{ $regitro->datanasc }}</td>
            <td>{{ $regitro->horaoco }}</td>
            <td>{{ $regitro->horache }}</td>
            <td>{{ $regitro->horalib }}</td>
            <td>{{ $regitro->ncnh}}</td>
            <td>{{ $regitro->cpf }}</td>
            <td>
              <a class="btn deep-orange" href="{{ route('admin.registrar.editar',$regitro->id) }}">Editar</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

O que está impossibilitando de eu buscar esses dados?

Comment: Qual o resultado? Algum código de erro? Como o código deveria funcionar?